# What perspective is suitable for sharing a screen across a table?

Tags: multiplayer, camera, multitouch

I'm thinking about a 2 player 2D arena game for a mobile phone, but I have the obvious problem of gripping. To avoid this, I think it shouldn't be a problem to play one in front of the other with touchscreen controls. The problem is, of course, the perspective of the sprites in the screen so they look okay to both players.

I'm thinking fully orthogonal perspective, but it hurts visibility a lot, specially if using human sprites viewed from the top of the head. Is there any example of a game that did this right?

[image: Example with spaceships]

Comment: Could you make things symmetrical?

Comment: Can you explain that a little more? The players would be fighting each other in real time, so I cannot make a horizontal mirror.

Comment: Make each sprite symmetric such that it is identical whether you view it from the top or the bottom.

Comment: How do you make a "full body" sprite symmetrical and goodlooking? That's my question.

GTA did it and it looked terrible: http://cdn1.spiele-umsonst.de/gta21.jpg

Also, Hotline Miami http://cdn2.steampowered.com/v/gfx/apps/219150/ss_75386edf15a48d844dc28ffdc61eb5c458d68533.1920x1080.jpg?t=1363804601

Comment: You didn't specify enough that I might know symmetry was not an option. Perhaps some more info would help.

Comment: Refer to the picture. Two players, one in front of the other, manipulating the same device in real time engaged in a game with humanoid sprites battling each other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8737/discussion-between-ef-es-and-stephelton)

Comment: Would be nice if you would come up with some kind of optical illusion as a solution.

Comment: Please specify whether this question is about 2D or 3D. This makes a big difference for your question, in my opinion.

Comment: 2D, sorry. I'm using libgdx

Answer (score 5):

Most any top down perspective will work. 2D games have done this in the past with games like PacMan:

[image]

Additionally, any top down perspective where the camera is at the center of the screen. This gives the kind of view you showed in your comment:

[image]

Both of these assume the players are sharing a play field. If the players are not sharing a play field, you can split the view symmetrically and draw two views in whatever perspective you want.

Comment: But the GTA view makes for really bad visibility, the sprites have to make very exaggerated movements to show what direction they are facing.

Comment: That sounds like a art problem, not a perspective problem. I can tell the direction all the sprites are facing in that image without any movement. With details like headlights/taillights and faces/back of heads, it makes it simple to know the direction.

Comment: I was wondering if there was another one that might work instead of rely everything on the artwork, hence the pre-edited "visibility problems" title. Not ingame perspective but art perspective.

Answer (score 3):

One good way is to use split screen. Take the 2D image and render it on a side angle (from the player's view). As long as the player is looking at their side there shouldn't be a problem. You can just add a 2D splitter in the middle of the screen.